Trivial Sigma Algebra Conditional Expectation Proof (Measurable Part)
I came across a classic exercise in probability theory: Prove $\mathbb{E}[X | \{\Omega, \emptyset\}] = \mathbb{E}[X]$, where $X$ is a random variable in $L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, with the conditional expectation:
$\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}] =: Y$ such that $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, $\mathbb{E}[|Y|] < \infty$, and $\forall A \in \mathcal{G}: \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_AY] = \int_{A}Yd\mathbb{P} = \int_AXd\mathbb{P}=\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_AX]$.
My issue is with the first part, that $Y=\mathbb{E}[X]$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, and I haven't seen it resolved in other posts. To me, $\mathbb{E}[X] := \int_{\Omega}Xd\mathbb{P}$ seems to be a function: $L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I don't see how measurability of $\mathbb{E}[X]$ coincides with what we need from $Y$.
To be specific, for $Y$ to be $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, don't we need: $\forall C \in \mathcal{C}, Y^{-1}(C) \in \mathcal{G}$? (Where $Y$ maps between measure spaces $(\Omega, \mathcal{G}) \rightarrow (\Omega', \mathcal{C})$. But if $Y: L^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then $Y^{-1}$ is a set of functions $\in L^1$. So how does it make sense to say that $Y^{-1} \in \{\Omega, \emptyset\}$?
I sense (Because I know that $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ is a function of $Y$) that my issue here is with the assumption of $Y$ as a function $L^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. But then precisely what measure spaces does $Y$ map between? If the conditional expectation is a random variable, then it is a function, so what are its domain and range? I.e. how do we get back to an inverse image that lives on $\Omega$, when the expectation doesn't seem to rely on $\omega$?
I feel that I'm getting tripped up on something simple here. Are any of my definitions incorrect? What am I missing here? Thanks.

You are totally right that in general, $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}]$ is a random variable (so it would be more accurate to write $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}](\omega)$. Assuming that you are working with real-valued random variables living on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, this means that they are measurable functions from $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ to $(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, i.e. the real line with its associated Borel $\sigma$-algebra. So any function $X(\omega): \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable or $\mathcal{F}$-measurable function if it satisfies
$$
X^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{F},\forall B \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}).
$$
Here $X^{-1}(B)$ is shorthand for $\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \in B\}$. So random variables are not functions from $L^{1}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, as you seem to imply if I understand correctly.
An element $X$ of $L^{1}(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is by definition 1) a random variable (= measurable function) and 2) satisfies $\mathbb{E}[|X|] < \infty$. So this space contains functions from $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ to $(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$, but the space itself does not play a role when determining measurability.
In the case that $\mathcal{G}$ is the trivial $\sigma$-algebra, any version of $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{G}]:= Y$ has to satify by the second requirement in your definition:
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\emptyset}Y] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\emptyset}X]
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\Omega}Y] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\Omega}X].
$$
Since the first requirement is always true for any random variable, you just need a random variable that satisfies
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\Omega}Y] =\mathbb{E}[Y] =  \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{\Omega}X] = \mathbb{E}[X],
$$
since $\mathbf{1}_{\Omega}(\omega) = 1$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$.
Therefore, if you choose the function
$$
Y(\omega) = \mathbb{E}[X], \forall \omega \in \Omega,
$$
it will satisfy the second requirement in your definition.
Now on to your question, it is not the case that $\mathbb{E}[X]$ is a function from $L^{1}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, as it is just some real number (assuming that $X$ is in $L^{1}$). What you have to show for the first part of the definition, is that
$$
Y^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{G}, \forall B \in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}).
$$
For the function $Y$ in question, this is easy, because a set $B$ will either contain $\mathbb{E}[X]$ or not. Suppose $\mathbb{E}[X] \in B$, then $Y^{-1}(B) = \Omega \in \mathcal{G}$; if $\mathbb{E}[X] \notin B$, then $Y^{-1}(B) = \emptyset \in \mathcal{G}$. Hence indeed we have that the above holds. Then also immediately it follows by the same logic that $Y$ is in fact a random variable ($\mathcal{F}$-measurable) because $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$.
Also, $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ in the measure-theoretic sense is just shorthand notation for $\mathbb{E}[X|\sigma(Y)]$, where $\sigma(Y)$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that makes $Y$ measurable (so by definition it is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$).

Thanks for the answer. In order for $Y^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{G}$ though, that means we have $Y: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, correct? So our measure spaces would be $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}), (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, with $\mathcal{G} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$. I guess what I don't see is how $Y$ can be a function of $\omega$, i.e. what actually is $Y(\omega)$? If we have the expectation as $\int_{\Omega} Xd\mathbb{P}$, this doesn't seem to rely on any $\omega$ at all, but rather on the measure space our variable is defined on.

You are right, $Y$ maps from the spaces you mention, in fact any random variable is by definition a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$. In particular, constant functions are also random variables, and the $Y$ that I defined in my answer is a constant function that maps all $\omega \in \Omega$ to the number $\int_{\Omega} X d\mathbb{P}$ (think of $f(x) = c, c\in\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. a horizontal line) which is also a function that does not explicitly depend on the input).

Ah okay that makes sense, exactly the example I needed, thanks.
